# float: left; for a container nested in a <section> results in the disappearing section height, is this expected behaviour?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to build a section of a website which consists of 3 containers aligned horizontally and a footer.

The containers has a class of class="box" and the footer is simply denoted as `<footer>`. The container is also nested in a section with id="boxes".

When a property of float: left; is applied to the class="box", the entire section of id="boxes" seems to vanish. The contents of class="box" nested within the section id="box" is still visible but the `<footer>` represents the whole region instead on section id="box".

Please see figure below

[image]

Seek advise if this is an expected behavior and how can I achieve the style that I am looking for :

1. 3 Containers, horizontally aligned
2. Footer at the bottom

Thanks!

ps: see below for attached snippet to see the issue that is being faced. notice that the `<footer>` cannibalises the `<section id="boxes">` region.

```css
#boxes .box {

    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 30%;
      padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .box img {
    width: 90px;
}

footer {
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>SMRT Logo</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
     <div class="box">
        <h1>Pimentos Del Pardon</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
     <div class="box">
         <h1>Tomato Plant</h1>
         <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
</section>

<footer>
    This is the fourth project &cc 2021
</footer>
```

Comment: Have amended the question to become more precise and if possible would seek assistance to re-open the question. Thanks.

Comment: Reopened, thanks for the edit. Was not expecting to see the SMRT logo in a Stack Overflow question, guess I can add that to my bucket list...

Answer (score 0):

`float: center` doesn't exist. What you're trying to do is have the footer *clear* the floating boxes. When it's not doing that, the behavior you're seeing is expected. You do that with `clear: both` (or `clear: left`, either works, but most people use "both" in case there are floats coming from both directions):

```css
#boxes .box {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .box img {
    width: 90px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>SMRT Logo</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
     <div class="box">
        <h1>Pimentos Del Pardon</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
     <div class="box">
         <h1>Tomato Plant</h1>
         <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
</section>

<footer>
    This is the fourth project &cc 2021
</footer>
```

These days grid and flexbox are the more viable layout options and [are](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) widely [supported](https://caniuse.com/flexbox). I recommend learning these eventually so you no longer have to worry about floats. Here's a grid example (which has the bonus of truly centering the boxes, where they were off-center before in your float layout):

```css
#boxes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#boxes .box {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .box img {
    width: 90px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>SMRT Logo</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
     <div class="box">
        <h1>Pimentos Del Pardon</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
     <div class="box">
         <h1>Tomato Plant</h1>
         <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHXhQgQJ6ky3JXZj-rCKJHjPXUJ6yynBkopg&usqp=CAU">
     </div>
</section>

<footer>
    This is the fourth project &cc 2021
</footer>
```